# Choosing the right metric for calculating losses

Tags: python, statistics, finance

Please help me choose the right metric for calculating losses.
Current metric:

```
Maximum losses = number of potentially lost customers * 
   median payment of potentially lost customers
Real losses = the number of really lost customers * 
   median payment of a really lost customers
Losses = real losses / maximum losses
```

Lost customers is a selection of potentially lost customers.
Therefore, real losses in practice should be always less than the maximum losses.

But in fact, real losses may be greater than maximum losses. E.g.
Maximum losses for customers:

```
1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3: 2 (median payment) * 9 (number of customers) = 18.
```

Real losses from the same population:

```
2 2 2 3 3 3 3: 3 (median payment) * 7 (number of customers) = 21.
```

Using the sum() instead of the median is impractical because the losses are extremely “skewed” and unstable.

Comment: Which language are you using? (Not that it really mattered for your question, but you might increase your audience :-)